# Как записывать стрим в файл, используя ffmpeg+python?

Tags: python, websocket, ffmpeg, subprocess

У меня есть простой websocket клиент на python, который получает чанки ogg трека ежесекундно. Мне нужно, чтобы ffmpeg в онлайн режиме записывал эти чанки в файл. Если это важно, я могу менять ogg на любой другой формат.
Моя реализация такая:

```py
async def hello(uri):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', 'ffmpeg.ogg'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE) #  или sys.stdout
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            r = await websocket.recv()
            process.stdin.write(r)  # или sys.stdout.write()
```

В результате ffmpeg даже не создает файл, в который должен все это записывать.
Вместо этого через несколько секунд появляется ошибка Broken pipe, а в случае с sys.stdout сам ffmpeg выводит:
`pipe:: Bad file descriptor`

**EDIT:**
Код для деления файла на чанки

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment

song = AudioSegment.from_ogg("tst.ogg")
current_offset = 0
offset = 1000
while True:
    chunk = song[current_offset:current_offset+offset]
    current_offset += offset
    websocket.send(chunk.raw_data)
```

Comment: Каков точный формат этих чанков? Если это не цельный ogg, то значит возможно у него нет каких-нибудь нужных ogg-заголовков, по которым можно было бы опознать ogg? Вы уверены, что ffmpeg может/должен уметь распознавать чанки?

Comment: Один чанк - 1 секунда. Я использую pydub для разбиения файла, он делит файл именно по миллисекундам, а не по байтам.
Ffmpeg успешно работает с rtmp или hls, там же тоже файл делится на части.

Comment: Делит это хорошо, но всё же каков точный формат чанков, которые делает pydub? Откуда уверенность, что этот формат должен распознаваться ffmpeg'ом?

Comment: Или покажите код, как вы делаете чанки, чтобы мы могли сами изучить получаемый формат

Comment: Добавил в EDIT.

Comment: У меня есть пример кода, который читает файл ogg (точнее перекодирует его и читает), используя ffmpeg, разбивает на чанки и отправляет через websocket. Этот пример отлично работает и websocket сервер воспроизводит аудио. Я взял размер чанков, который там используется и частично скопировал код. Это не помогло, ffmpeg не создает ffmpeg.ogg даже пустой

Comment: Каким образом `ffmpeg` знает о входном потоке? Для упомянутых вами там специальный протокол, который это умеет, а у вас не пойми что (с точки зрения входного потока). В общем вам и надо что-то типа rtmp организовывать.

Comment: я отталкивался от того, что ffmpeg все-таки умеет в качестве входа принимать stdin, потому что команда ffmpeg -i - out.ogg < in.ogg работает, хотя здесь для него расширение входного файла тоже неизвестно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается добавлением опции `-re` к запуску ffmpeg:
`ffmpeg -re -i - ffmpeg.ogg`
И при отправке чанков сначала кодируем каждый чанк в ogg, используя pydub:

```py
data = chunk.export('bin/chunk.ogg', 'ogg').read()
await websocket.send(data)
```